# warning on a specific page only (on click on back, on menu, on button)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, warnings

I have a problem. In web application, where administrator(my customer) can edit orders. He wants a warnings to prevent loosing work. Warning if you click on: 
 - butons(Save, WorkOrder, DeliveryNote..)
 - on left menu (i use Master.page)
 - on explorer button Back..

I can do that only with window.onbeforeunload() in That admin page, calling it form master page.

But problem is that it only returns default explorer message for all moves the same.

btw, this is not good, because on button save it ask you "if you are sure to leave the page" in other cases it is OK. Ony for save isn't.

I put custom warnings on single buttons, but I can't in Menu, because I want to have warnings only in specific form.

I'm thinking to do onother Master page, only for that page...

Have you eny idea, how to handle this?

Thanks fellow :)

edited:

I figured, sorry

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.change-control').change(function () {
              jQuery('td#Menu a, .button.report').click(function (e) {
                 if (confirm('Warning, unsaved order changes will be lost!')) {
                  }
                  else {
                     e.preventDefault();
                  }
            });
        });
    });
```

Problem remains how to add Warning to clickon explorer-back button?
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> I put custom warnings on single buttons, but I can't in Menu, because I want to have warnings only in specific form.

What about making you javascript function looking to the current browser page (use  "[window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)" object)  to show messages from menu items clicks, only where you are in your specific form page? Could work, but be aware about page renaming...